# Closed Form Formula for AGM

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I have seen a closed form formula for the arithmetic-geometric mean of complex numbers that involved the inverse sinh function, but now I cannot find it anywhere.  Can somebody lead me there?   I want to compute the AGM directly.

Comment: Perhaps your memory is a bit off.  The AGM can be expressed in terms of an elliptic integral, and it not elementary, but $\mathrm{asinh}$ is elementary.  See `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic–geometric_mean#Proof_of_the_integral-form_expression`

Comment: I do love the asinh function for data compression:  it is linear for small signals, but becomes logarithmic for large ones.  Sometimes that is what you need if you are trying for a large dynamic range (earthquakes in California).  Note that there is another form of the AGM by Borchardt that does not converge quadratically.  I know AGM(1,x) is (x-1)/Ln(x).   Warning: if you use this to compute a log, I will call the logarithm police on you!